# My mongo is not showing in C Drive

Tags: mongodb

I installed mongodb and it was installed successfully in `c:\mongodb`. However, the folder is not present inside that folder and either the folder is not in program file.

Comment: Are you sure it is installed? See the last message on last step of installation

Comment: The last message was mongodb is installed successfully

Answer (score 0):

did you check whether mongodb was installed successfully or not this way from cmd:

> mongo -version